# Inverse mellin transform

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function, bessel-functions

Let $K_1(t)$ be the K-Bessel function, then we have

$\int_{0}^{\infty}K_v(y)y^s\frac{dy}{y}=2^{s-2}\Gamma(\frac{s+v}{2})\Gamma(\frac{s-v}{2})$ See page 106 of Bump's book Automorphic forms and representations.

I need a proof of the inverse Mellin transform

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C-i\infty}^{C+i\infty}\frac{\Gamma(z+3)\Gamma(z+2)}{z}\left(\frac{N}{4\pi^2nA}\right)^zdz=\frac{1}{8}G_1\left(4\pi\sqrt{\frac{nA}{N}}\right),$$
where $$G_1(x)=\int_{x}^{\infty}t^4K_1(t)dt$$

Comment: take the derivative with respect to $u=N/A$ and it becomes the usual inverse Mellin.

Comment: Thank you for saving the day!